# CSS: select first occurrence of link containing specific word

Tags: css

Imagine the following example:

```
<a href="/test/test.html"></a>
<a href="/test/test.html"></a>
<a href="/test/test.html"></a>
**<a href="/info/test.html"></a>**
<a href="/info/test.html"></a>
<a href="/info/test.html"></a>
```

Is it possible to get the fourth item?

**Note:** I need only CSS solution as I already know the way of doing in JS. Can't use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` as it can be any position in a list. There is only one wrapping container for all the links.

This is how I have tried to achieve what I want:

```
a[href*="/info/"]:first-child:before {
    content: "Pages";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #b1be2d;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 120%; 
}
```

Comment: CSS can't select like that based on content or attribute ...so no. Remember that CSS selects right to left so if it's not the `:first-child` the selector fails and so on.

Comment: I had a hope, now you have screwed my life :) Thanks @Paulie_D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do exactly that...

I don't know if this would help you, but you *can* select everyone that is *not* the first occurrence, using a general sibling selector... This way you'd be able to differ the styling of the first ocurrence from the rest of them:

```
a[href*="/info/"] {
    /* style for every occurence */
}

a[href*="/info/"] ~ a[href*="/info/"] {
    /* style for every occurence that is not the first one */
}
```

[**JsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vbaoq9gb/)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I found myself :)